# Execute jQuery after Bootstrap Modal Closes

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to execute some jQuery code after a Bootstrap modal is closed on my page, I have the id of the modal in my jQuery and everything. I'd like to use a jQuery function of some sort, as opposed to a conditional if-statement. This is the modal which I have open, how would I run some jQuery after it's closed (The animation should be complete and everything)?

```
<div id="part_number-modal" class="modal fade in" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="part_number-modal" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
<!-- the rest of the modal HTML is in here -->
</div>
```

Comment: You want jQuery to close your modal?

Comment: @Cyzanfar I think I said I'd like to execute some jQuery "after" the modal is closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [hidden event](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) handler

> This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the
>   user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

```
$('#part_number-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something...
})
```

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked [the documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)?

```
$('#part_number-modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
  // do something after modal is hidden...
})
```